# Recursive directory traversal in Perl

Tags: perl, recursion

I'm trying to write a script that prints out the file structure starting at the folder the script is located in. The script works fine without the recursive call but with that call it prints the contents of the first folder and crashes with the following message: closedir() attempted on invalid dirhandle DIR at printFiles.pl line 24. The folders are printed and the execution reaches the last line but why isn't the recursive call done? And how should I solve this instead?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

printDir(".");
sub printDir{
opendir(DIR, $_[0]);
local(@files);
local(@dirs);
 (@files) = readdir(DIR);
 foreach $file (@files) {
    if (-f $file) {
      print $file . "\n";
    }
    if (-d $file && $file ne "." && $file ne "..") {
      push(@dirs, $file);
    }
 } 
 foreach $dir (@dirs) {
   print "\n";
   print $dir . "\n";
   printDir($dir);
 }
 closedir(DIR);
}
```

Comment: I know but it's not funny to do it the easy way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the start of your Perl program, especially before you ask for help with it. That way Perl will show up a lot of straightforward errors that you may not notice otherwise.
- The *invalid filehandle* error is likely because `DIR` is a global directory handle and has been closed already by a previous execution of the subroutine. It is best to always used lexical handles for both files and directories, and to test the return code to make sure the open succeeded, like this

  ```
  opendir my $dh, $_[0] or die "Failed to open $_[0]: $!";
  ```

  One advantage of lexical file handles is that they are closed implicitly when they go out of scope, so there is no need for your `closedir` call at the end of the subroutine.
- `local` isn't meant to be used like that. It doesn't suffice as a declaration, and you are creating a temporary copy of a global variable that everything can access. Best to use `my` instead, like this

  ```
  my @dirs;
  my @files = readdir $dh;
  ```
- Also, the file names you are using from `readdir` have no path, and so your file tests will fail unless you either `chdir` to the directory being processed or append the directory path string to the file name before testing it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module. The way i usually do this is using the [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html) tool which comes with perl, which takes the same parameters as *find* and creates a suitable perl script using File::Find. Then i fine-tune the generated script to do what i want it to do. But it's also possible to use File::Find directly.

Answer (score 3):

Why not [`use File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)?

```
use strict; #ALWAYS!
use warnings; #ALWAYS!
use File::Find;

find(sub{print "$_\n";},".");
```